Converting Lunchbox Singer sewing machine to Cabinet mount?
I have a vintage Singer 306 with a clip-on cover and a wooden cabinet from another Singer.  I wish to install the machine into the cabinet.  What items do I need, and what else have I failed to consider?
The cabinet has lost all its treadle components at some time in the past.  The only trace remaining are screw holes.
1. Hinges at the rear:
I have these hinges at the moment:

and I believe I need two of this style, and wood screws:

I have found these Black Sewing Machine Cabinet Hinge Fit For Singer 15-30 + knockoff/aftermarket hinges.
 They appear to be correct and I have ordered.
2. Cover plate
Where the treadle strap used to go - not sure of a name for this:

I think this plate is cosmetic, and serves to stop scissors from dropping down.  What would you call it?
Here's my machine mocked up on the cabinet, showing the gap on the right:

3. Curved board
When the machine is folded away, there is supposed to be a thin "knee board"   This cabinet lacks any of that.  Does it serve any purpose?
Does the machine just hang under its own weight from the two hinges when stowed?
And - what else have I overlooked?

Short answer:  Works fine!
Caveats - I don't have all the parts from the cabinet, so there are some potential problems

Oil drips falling from machine to whatever is stashed inside the cabinet
User could touch moving parts underneath
Dropping something through the treadle power hatch while in use
Dropping the whole machine off its hinges when stowed.


Zooming in on the old hinge, shows the flat for the grub screw.  I ended up making a new lid for this box, and filling it with Gridfinity boxes for storage.

The "lunchbox" case has this little prop on the right-hand side.  There is nowhere to connect it to on the floor cabinet, so changing the bobbin means laying the whole machine back.   (the 306 bobbin is underneath the machine, not accessed through the footplate like a 201.)

The hinges were not exactly well-made.  Some filing was required to make it sit flush and flat.

 Close up of the hinges, showing filing needed.

 I pulled a screw from the cabinet's lid hinge, and they're too small.  The screw for the two machine hinges is thicker and slightly longer.  I found a couple in my misc screws jar and cleaned them up on a wire wheel.

 The entire weight of the machine is hanging from the two hinges when its lowered.  This feels unwise - the whole machine is supported by only two grub screws into the two hinges.  I will not store the machine stowed normally.

I need to cut something to fill that hole, but not interfere with lowering.  At the moment, that's where I'd normally stow scissors.

 There is nothing under the machine, to catch oil or prevent the user from touching a rotating part.  There should be a large curved piece of thin wood.

I also took the chance to replace the bobbin winder tyre, and other misc parts.  Was not expensive, and provides the finishing touches.  Be aware to not block an oil port thinking it is a thread holder peg.
Other learnings: The Singer 306 uses a weird shorter needle length.  If you use the wrong one, it will hit the bobbin-holder case and cause damage to both.
ALSO you need L-style bobbins which are not the same as regular A-style bobbins.   All these things were found on Aliexpress.
My 306k does NOT have pattern disks / fashion disks, which is disappointing but not a huge loss.
